# Is the Legendary Surge die size limited to d8?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The reading of the Legendary surge ability is as below.

> The legendary surge ability allows the bearer to add the result of a d6 to the appropriate type of roll or check. A mythic bearer can use her surge die type in place of the d6. **If she's bonded to the item, she can increase that die type by one step.**

Emphasis mine.

I understand that a mythic character can use their surge die in place of the legendary surge die but the last sentence is not clear.

Is it limiting the die to one die step up when using legendary(So the highest would be a d8), OR does it mean if the character's surge die is a d8 the surge would be one step higher and be a d10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It is an additional increase, over and above the possible increase from Mythic

The Mythic effect is not “increasing” the die type, it is “setting” the die type, equal to the type of her surge die. Thus, the following sentence cannot be read as limiting the “increase,” because up to that point there hasn’t *been* an increase to limit.

Thus, though the bolded sentence is ambiguous on its own, within the context that it appears there is only one way it can be read. Specifically, the only possible reading of that line is as a separate increase, over and above the change to the die’s type to make it match the surge die’s type.